# How to retrieve a quantum state after passing through a series of quantum gates?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state

Consider a qubit

$$\left| \psi \right> = (\alpha_1 + i\alpha_2 ) \left|0\right> + (\beta_1 + i\beta_2 )\left|1\right>$$

Now if i pass this through a series of  quantum gates or any typical quantum circuit can I know the values of $\alpha$'s &$\beta$'s. before measuring it or without measuring it?

Comment: what do you mean "before measuring it or without measuring it?"  you could run your circuit in reverse to revert back to the original state.

Comment: I mean is it possible for me to see the amplitude values or the probabilities of being in state zero or state one.(in complex form like original)

Answer (score 1):

The single qubit state is
$$|\psi \rangle = \alpha |0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix} \hspace{2 cm} \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$$
and **if you know** what $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is ahead of time then of course you can keep track of all the matrix vector multiplications as applying a quantum gate is nothing but applying a unitary matrix, $U \in \mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{C}^2 \ \ \ \textrm{s.t} \ \ \ U^\dagger U = I   $,  to the vector $|\psi \rangle$. So from the information of the resulting vector from the matrix-vector multiplcation, you can determine the probability of observing $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. This is what it is being done if you use something like [`statevector_simulator`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.StatevectorSimulator.html) fro Qiskit.

For a single qubit, this is not a problem... but when you start getting into the 50 qubits range... storing $2^{50}$ complex values is quite daunting already and we are not talking about the cost of matrix-vector multiplication yet. With all that being said, here I am assuming a general setting. There are cases where this exact simulation can be done efficiently classically.